# summarize the previous rows with conditions, python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, summarize

I am new in python. I have a question about how to summarize the previous rows. The dataset is:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'reason':['B','A','B','A','A','A','B','A'],'result':['W','W','Z','X','X','W','Z','W']})

        ID  reason  result
0       1      B      W
1       1      A      W
2       1      B      Z
3       1      A      X
4       2      A      X
5       2      A      W
6       2      B      Z
7       2      A      W
```

I want to summarize the history data (previous rows) of reason with the same ID. And I also want to summarize the history data of result with reason A. The results should look like:

```
    ID   reason result   Previous_reason  Previous_result_reasonA
0   1      B      W
1   1      A      W         B
2   1      B      Z         B|A              W
3   1      A      X         B|A|B            W
4   2      A      X
5   2      A      W         A                X
6   2      B      Z         A|A              X|W
7   2      A      W         A|A|B            X|W
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `DataFrame` is sorted by `ID`, you can solve it O(n):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                   'reason':['B','A','B','A','A','A','B','A'],
                   'result':['W','W','Z','X','X','W','Z','W']})

df['Previous_reason'] = [''] * len(df)
df['Previous_result_reasonA'] = [''] * len(df)

result_reasonA = ''

for r in range(1, len(df)):
    if df['ID'][r] == df['ID'][r-1]:
        df.loc[r, 'Previous_reason'] = \
            df['Previous_reason'][r-1] + '|' + df['reason'][r-1]
        df.loc[r, 'Previous_result_reasonA'] = \
            df['Previous_result_reasonA'][r-1]
        if result_reasonA:
            df.loc[r, 'Previous_result_reasonA'] += \
                '|' + result_reasonA
    else:
        df.loc[r, 'Previous_reason'] = ''

    if df['reason'][r] == 'A':
        result_reasonA = df['result'][r]
    else:
        result_reasonA = ''

# Clear trailing `|` separators
df['Previous_reason'] = \
    df['Previous_reason'].apply(lambda x: x[1:])
df['Previous_result_reasonA'] = \
    df['Previous_result_reasonA'].apply(lambda x: x[1:])

print df
```

Output:

```
   ID reason result Previous_reason Previous_result_reasonA
0   1      B      W                                        
1   1      A      W               B                        
2   1      B      Z             B|A                       W
3   1      A      X           B|A|B                       W
4   2      A      X                                        
5   2      A      W               A                       X
6   2      B      Z             A|A                     X|W
7   2      A      W           A|A|B                     X|W
```

The question is, however, if all special cases are covered. This I can not be aware of, as I do not know the meaning of data.

Comment: Thank a lot! It worked perfectly. However, I have about 0.5 million rows. Is there a more efficiency way on big data. I am thinking of groupby, then agg/cumsum. But not very sure how to apply it.

Comment: That said, I have an impression you would be OK with completely different output format than in your original question. Is that right? Are you interested in final lists of `reason` and `reasonA` values only? (i.e. `B|A|B` and `X|W`).

Comment: The finial result will be very similar. I am interested in final lists of reason, reasonA  and reason B. Just worried about the efficiency of loop on big data.

Comment: Does the loop on 0.5 million rows take much time for you? And what time would you be interested in? Above solution should not cost much, but probably it can be improved by hacking a few Pandas' built-ins.